# How can I keep a TextField in a single run in a Wrap until it reaches a minimum width?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

**Display:**

[image]

**Code**

```
Card(
   child: Wrap(children: [
      Text('Hi. What\'s your name?'),
      Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 300), child: TextField())
    ]))
```

**Demo**

https://dartpad.dev/65527c29343bd9afca842dff66907e6f?null_safety=true

**What's needed**

I would like for the `TextField` to run adjacent to right of the `Text`. It should have a minimum constraint width of `300`. Then if the available space to the right of the `Text` is less than `300`, it should wrap and place itself below the text.

Basically, I need to implement similar method to `Expadable` for the `TextField` that only covers the first run of the Wrap.

**Problem**

The `TextField` automatically extends to the largest possible width.
Because this is a `Wrap`, it automatically sends it below the initial `Text` where it has the most available width.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Row` Widget instead of `Wrap` and expand the text

```
Card(
  child: Row(children: [
    Expanded(child: Text('Hi. What\'s your name?')),
    Container(width: 300, child: TextField())
  ]),
),
```

[image: Output]

Comment: It won't Wrap when it reaches its minimum width though... I don't want to use a Row. I want to use a Wrap.